# Is it possible to have multiple orgs configured on one heroku connect instance?

Tags: org, heroku-connect

I have an app that has heroku connect, how to create a connection on heroku connect but with mulitple salesforce orgs?

Answer (score 1):

You can add Multiple Addons of the same type as shown below

[image]

This gets you to connect to multiple Salesforce instances. Here is a [blogpost](https://medium.com/salesforce-architects/multi-org-visibility-for-work-com-9a618f73d003) showing this capability in action.

Comment: Thank you @Mohith that was I had in my mind (many heroku connect) but for some reasons, i will need to have 2 Heroku connects in my app, for 2 differents Salesforce orgs, but both of them will mappe same table (so in my postgres db i'll have schema1.tableX and schema2.tableX, both tables are exactely the same) I find it not really officient, any way to have same schema (in order to not duplicate same table)?